# System Tray icons not showing

Tags: google-chrome, notification, system-tray

After installing a fresh 14.04 install and then installing google-chrome-unstable (*Version 36.0.1933.0 dev aura*) from the google repository, neither the google chrome icon nor the 'Google Now' notification bell icon appear on the notification bar.

In all my previous installs it would appear as soon as I launched Chrome for the first time after installing. I've naturally tried rebooting, reinstalling and making sure the "*Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed*" setting enabled.

Edit: After installing Dropbox I noticed its tray icon isn't showing either, so I figured it was a global issue rather than chrome-specific. Eventually found the solution below (see answer).

Comment: In Chromium, sometimes the notification icon shows up, sometimes it doesn't. I think (at least in my case) it shows up only when a notification has been sent from an app.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it. I tried a test notification with pushbullet and the notification does pop up, but still no icon on the tray.

Comment: I've also just installed Dropbox and its system tray icon doesn't show either, so it must be something global rather than chrome-specific.

Comment: Technically, 14.04 is yet to be released, so there is a small chance that a package needs to be updated. Just to check, this is standard Ubuntu 14.04 with Unity, right? Mir is not enabled?

Comment: I just ran into this issue with on 14.04 (stable) machine---so the problem is not specific only to development versions as the question closure notice implies. It looks like this problem is in the process of being fixed in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=374686

Comment: A little more mundane, but this can also happen if you accidentally uncheck the "Let Google Chrome run in the background" menu item entry. You can re-enable the tray icon from the Advanced Settings, checkbox "Continue running background apps when Google Chrome is closed.".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Managed to solve it by installing libappindicator:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

Not sure why it was missing in the first place, but now everything's working fine again.