# Xubuntu 14.04 - Chromium didn't shut down correctly

Tags: xubuntu, 14.04, chromium

Today I installed the new (X)Ubuntu release 14.04 and installed my favorite internet browser "Chromium" via the repositories. However, Chromium always complains that:

`Chromium didn't shut down correctly. To reopen the pages you had open, click restore.`

when i open it, after a reboot, although I am shutting down Chromium in the usual way (x button). Anybody facing the same problem, and knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

What resolved to me was entering menu Settings > Shown advanced settings > System and uncheck Continue running background apps when Chrome is closed. I don't feel any negative impact by disable this option. I hope had helped.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The same problem appeared in my Ubuntu Unity 14.04 when I enabled Chrome (and Hangouts) to run in the background. Disabling it makes the problem go away. Unfortunately, the two icons in Notifications no longer appears as it did in 13.10. I first fixed that:

```
sudo apt-get install libappindicator1
```

at: [System Tray icons not showing [closed]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447739/system-tray-icons-not-showing)

That got the icons showing. So now, if you close out Chrome by right-clicking the Chrome icon and select "Exit" before shutting down, the problem goes away.

Not a real solution, because (I believe) Chrome background task is not shutting down on OS shutdown.

Comment: I would like to address this issue properly. Should I report this issue at the Chromium bug tracker or the Ubuntu bug tracker?